# Passing RequestHeader Play2.1

Tags: playframework-2.1, scala-2.10

I have a Problem in compiling play 2.1 application ,in   main.scala.html I called javascriptRouters

```
javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
routes.javascript.Authentication.authenticate
```

For this I have defined (request: play.api.mvc.RequestHeader) on top level 
so its working fine  now I got request object in this page but when calling 
@main("title")

```
  Unspecified value parameter content.
[error] @main(title = "Create Job",status,role){
```

how to pass request object ????

`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by passing it in the new parenthesis   but have a new questions

1. why it is not working when  passed it with content
2. The first one I understand that whenever I am calling @main I have to passs three string
3. what does second parenthesis mean (content :Html) are we passing the caller html here

   that what does this mean?

   @(title:String, status:Option[String],role:String)(content: Html)(implicit  request: play.api.mvc.RequestHeader)